# Azure Functions SQL-GET stopped running - HTTP ERROR 500. Python 3.9, but works locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

```
I Am very new in Azure Programming. 

For weeks I have had 2 functions in a function application that provide me with values ​​from an SQL database.They are triggered by an HTTP call. When I run the function today, I get an HTTP 500 error returned. **No changes** were made to the code.
Does anyone know this problem and can tell me how I can solve this?

I can run the app locally on my Windows PC in VS Code- Virtual Environment

Locally everything works as it should.
```

- Changed the Prcing tier
- New Function app - same Code
- Code Changes to fundamental HTTP- Get Requesting

everything failes.

Answer (score 1):

I could answer this question by myself. The issue is that depending on which place u choose to publish your app, the "azure-function" has problems. At this side i found specific information and the solution.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1029

Comment: Make your link to this format `[text](url link)`